# TFS Powershell Custom Release Task Execution error

Tags: json, powershell, tfs, release

I have successfully written some custom build tasks for TFS using Powershell. Now I have to write a release build tasks. First everything worked properly, but today I got some error:

```
ScriptName doesn't indicate a full path to a Powershell script.
##[error]Script file not found: SqlInstaller.ps1
```

As I looked around, there are two shools around:
One says in the descriptor task.json file I have to write the target as a pure file name, where the addresses powershell script have to be in the same folder where the task.json is:

```
   "execution": {
      "PowerShell": {
            "target": "SqlInstaller.ps1",
            "argumentFormat": "",
            "workingDirectory": "$(currentDirectory)"
```

Second says I have to write:

```
   "execution": {
      "PowerShell": {
            "target": "$(currentDirectory)\\SqlInstaller.ps1",
            "argumentFormat": "",
            "workingDirectory": "$(currentDirectory)"
```

Sadly, today none of them is working, both drops the same error message. :( What is the solution?

Comment: Did your mean the custom build task ever worked and suddenly not worked ? Did something changed during these days?

Comment: Yes, the scripts suddenly stopped working, and the error message started to appear in the log. Nothing has happened (as I asked the IT guys). Yesterday the "target": "$(currentDirectory)\\SqlInstaller.ps1", and "workingDirectory": "$(currentDirectory)" version suddenly started to work again. Now it works again. I don't know why...